# How to loop dataframe columns to sort the dataframe iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, loops, sorting, dataframe

I need to sort my dataframe according to different columns, for all columns, and I would like to do it with a loop. So I would need something like:

```
for j in range(nC):

    Elab1 = Elab1.sort_values([j, 13])
    Elab1 = Elab1.reset_index(drop=True)


    for i in range(L_GI-1):


        if Elab1.at[i+1, j] == Elab1.at[i, j] :


            Elab1.at[i+1, j+nC] = Elab1.at[i, j+nC]
```

`L_GI` and `nC` are respectively number of rows and columns of my dataframe: `Elab1`, while j and 13 are the position of the columns of my dataframe that I would like to use as sorting indexes.

While this works for looping rows, It does not work for columns, because I guess that with method `at` I need their name.
Is there a method to substitute the method `at`,  to use as shown in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `iloc` instead of `at`:

```
Elab1.iloc[i+1, j] == Elab1.iloc[i,j]
```

Comment: I am getting an error at this line: Elab1 = Elab1.sort_values([j, 13])  , I can substitute 13 with the designed column name, but how to replace j ?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Substitute

```
    if Elab1.at[i+1, j] == Elab1.at[i, j] :


        Elab1.at[i+1, j+nC] = Elab1.at[i, j+nC]
```

with

```
    if Elab1.iloc[i+1, j+nC] == Elab1.iloc[i, j+nC] :

            Elab1.iloc[i+1, j] = Elab1.iloc[i, j]
```

and substitute

```
[j, 13]
```

with

```
[columns_names_array[j], "constant_column_name"]
```

where

```
columns_names_array = [column_name in Elab1.columns()]
```

Best answer goes to @LeoE that pointed me the right way.

Comment: You could also just replace `columns_names_array[j]` to `list(data.columns)[j]` This way you don't need an extra variable to carry around